# How do I fix 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_entry_to_mysql' for inventory input, python-mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, database, tkinter, mysql-python

I am pretty new to Python, but for a team design project I need to create a code to input information into a Tkinter window that is connected to a mysql table and update that table accordingly. If the same ID is inputted again it should update the quantity +1 :

```
from Tkinter import*
import tkMessageBox
import tkFont
import mysql.connector
import time



def AddItem():
    print "Added Item"
    print "ID:" + ID.get()
    print "Item Name:" + ItemName.get()
    print "Price Per Item:" + PricePerItem.get()
    print "Manufacturer:" + Manufacturer.get()
```

The s = INSERT INTO inventory... is throwing me for a loop, I can input the information into the Tkinter window but when I select the Add Item button, this error shows up:

**ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_entry_to_mysql'**

```
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='cj92cj',
                                  database='INVENTORY', use_unicode=False)
    s = "INSERT INTO inventory (ID, Manufacturer, ItemName, PricePerItem, Quantity) VALUES({},{},{},{},1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Quantity= Quantity + 1, Manufacturer = VALUES(Manufacturer), ItemName = VALUES(ItemName), PricePerItem = VALUES(PricePerItem);".format(ID.get(),Manufacturer.get(),ItemName.get(),PricePerItem.get())

    print ID.get()
    print s
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(s, (ID, Manufacturer, ItemName, PricePerItem, Quantity))
    cursor.close()
    cnx.commit()
    cnx.close()

def ClearEntries():
    ItemName.delete(0,END)
    PricePerItem.delete(0,END)
    Manufacturer.delete(0,END)
```

I have been trying all sorts of things with "s" for hours and hours but I am having trouble figuring out the right syntax to use.

Below is the Tkinter Window code if that helps at all.

```
def InformationInput():
    BigFont=tkFont.Font(family="Arial", size=14, weight="bold")
    root.title("Enter Item Information") 
    root.geometry("1000x400")
    root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: AddItem())
    lbl1 = Label(root, text="ID:")
    lbl2 = Label(root, text="Item Name:") 
    lbl3 = Label(root, text="Price Per Item:")
    lbl4 = Label(root, text="Manufacturer:")
    lbl9 = Label(root, text="Enter Item Information", height=3, fg="red", font=BigFont)

    global ID, ItemName, PricePerItem, Manufacturer
    ID = Entry(root, width=25, textvariable=ID)
    ItemName = Entry(root, width=20, textvariable=ItemName) 
    PricePerItem = Entry(root, width=10, textvariable=PricePerItem) 
    Manufacturer = Entry(root, width=25, textvariable=Manufacturer)
    button1 = Button(root, text="Add Item", command=AddItem, width=15) 
    button2 = Button(root, text="Clear Entries", command=ClearEntries, width=15) 
    button3 = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy, width=15)

    lbl9.grid(column=2, row=1, columnspan=5) 
    lbl1.grid(column = 1, row = 4, sticky="nw") 
    ID.grid(column = 2, row = 4, sticky="nw") 
    lbl2.grid(column = 3, row = 4) 
    ItemName.grid(column = 4, row = 4) 
    lbl3.grid(column = 5, row = 4) 
    PricePerItem.grid(column = 6, row = 4, sticky="w")
    lbl4.grid(column = 3, row = 10)
    Manufacturer.grid(column = 4, row = 10)
    button1.grid(column=3, row=15, sticky="e", pady=20) 
    button2.grid(column=4, row=15) 
    button3.grid(column=5, row=15, sticky="w")



root = Tk()
ID = IntVar()
ItemName = StringVar() 
PricePerItem = IntVar() 
Manufacturer = StringVar() 
Quantity = IntVar()

InformationInput() 
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use parameter marks in your query or your database driver, in this case MySQL Connector/Python, will through an error. Also, you have to pass values which can be converted. `MySQLConverter` does not know how to convert `entry`-objects, so it tells you it can't convert it (although it can be a bit more explicit).

Here is an example (simplified):

```
s = ("INSERT INTO inventory (ID, Manufacturer, ItemName, PricePerItem, Quantity) "
     "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUP..")
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(s, (ID.get(), Manufacturer.get(), ItemName.get(),
                   PricePerItem.get(), Quantity.get()))
```

I took the liberty [opening a bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/71729) to improve the error message.

Other remark: I don't think you need to give the ID when inserting? Usually that is an AUTO_INCREMENT.